# Why is 7 handled as a negative number in the following equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is a very simple multi-step equation that bothered me for a specific reason:

20-7x=6x-6

I started by subtracting 6x from both sides and for a second I thought I would find "1x" as a result of subtracting 6x from the left side of the equation (and write it as 20-1x=-6). then I realized that it should have been "-13 x" (20-13x=-6)

Although I could solve it mechanically, I couldn't internalize the logic behind evaluating a subtraction sign as a negative number symbol in algebraic equations. Why should one get the "-" sign before 7x as a negative sign and conduct the subtraction operation accordingly? I would appreciate an answer that covers the logic behind this action.

Comment: $20-7x$ means $20+(-7)x$.

Comment: Subtraction is not an associative operation, i.e., $(a-b)-c\not=a-(b-c)$. When you bring the $6x$ over to get $20-7x-6x$, you should interpret it as $(20-7x)-6x=20-(7x+6x)=20-13x$, not $20-(7x-6x)=20-x$.

Comment: In general the difference $a-b$ is defined to be $a+(-b)$ where $-b$ is the additive inverse of $b$ (*the unique number which when added to $b$ results in zero*).  As mentioned, $20-7x$ is then $20+(-(7x))$ which could be rewritten as $20+(-7)x$ if one wished.

Comment: Thank you all! I have a sound understanding of the concept now.